# Splash Screen strange Black Rectangle on screen

Tags: android, splash-screen, nine-patch

> **UPDATE:** Finally find a little bit hacky solution. But it's not acceptable for me. All ideas can be useful.

I have a Splash Screen Activity and I do not use setContentView().
I set background from **styles.xml** with using **android:windowBackground**

When splash screen started, a **black rectangle** shows up from nowhere, located at left lower part of screen. Height is exact same height with NavigationBar, starts from left of the screen and ends at the center of screen.

This black rectangle **only appears** at devices, which **have Navigation Bar**. Not physical buttons. And also only visible when try to **hide or show Navigation Bar** at a **FullScreen** activity.

> **QUESTION:** What can be the reason of this bug? How can I solve it?

You can see the whole event below. (Splash Screen to Login screen transition)

[image]

**Here my splash activity style:**

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

**background_splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    //Tried different colored layer at bottom level but did not affect
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/grey_Dark"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    //Background image
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/bg"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    //9-patch Logo at the center
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/splash_logo"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</layer-list>
```

**ActivitySplash**

```
public class ActivitySplash extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ActivitySplash.this, ActivityLogin.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }, 2000);

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you inspected this issue with "show layout bounds" on? Is that actually some view there?

Comment: @azizbekian posted an answer, you can check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally find a little bit hacky solution. But it's not acceptable for me. Any ideas can be useful.

First, used Layout Inspector and get this result:

[image]

Under **DecorView**, there is an unwanted strange **View** is created after started the splash activity.

It blinks in half of a second and disappears.

After blinking, If user triggers screen for showing the Navigation Bar, this strange View appears again (permanently).

Blinking view disappeared after adding

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

to my activitty style.

Other part is more complicated.
Added a **OnHierarchyChangeListener** to DecorView of activity. Casted my DecorView into FrameLayout, and Override **onChildViewAdded()** callback to remove all children after adding to **DecorView**.

```
final FrameLayout myDecorView = (FrameLayout) decorView;
myDecorView.setOnHierarchyChangeListener(new ViewGroup.OnHierarchyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildViewAdded(View parent, View child) {
        myDecorView.removeView(child);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildViewRemoved(View parent, View child) {

    }
});
```